# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in component Constructor

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have seen this question asked a lot but I can't find an answer specifically related to the error being in the constructor/super.

ClassB extends ClassA. ClassA is empty besides a few protected variables. ClassB has a a constructor which looks like this:

```
constructor(
        protected route: ActivatedRoute,
        protected recipesService: RecipesService) {
        super(route)
    }
```

The error

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

is on super and I know it has the wrong number of parameters.

But where is the call target? What is determining how many parameters it's supposed to have?